# Retrieving Records From Entity in Dynamics Crm using odata and jquery

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I want to print the values retrieved from my entity in an alert message.I store the values in relatedproduct array i want to print these value.When it try to print them it gives undefined message.Plz help me

```js
    relatedProducts = [];

    function onload() {
       var oDataUri="https://yanceyworksllc.crm.dynamics.com/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ProductSet?$select=new_price,ProductId&$filter=new_TaxInformation/Value eq 1";
       GetRecords(oDataUri);
       var totalRecords = relatedProducts .length;
    }

    function GetRecords(url) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            url: url,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
             var x=   XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                if (data && data.d != null && data.d.results != null) {
                    AddRecordsToArray(data.d.results);
                    FetchRecordsCallBack(data.d);
                }
            },
            error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             //  FetchRecordsCallBack(data.d);
                alert("Error :  has occured during retrieval of the records ");
            }
        });
    }

    function AddRecordsToArray(records) {
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            relatedProducts .push(records[i]);
           alert(relatedProducts[i].Value) ;

        }

    }

    function FetchRecordsCallBack(records) {
        if (records.__next != null) {
            var url = records.__next;
            GetRecords(url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Mike_Matthews_II The ordering of function declarations is not important as the script is interpreted THEN executed.  Even if GetRecords was a self executing function (which it isn't) it would still be valid.  In isolation this piece of code wouldn't actually do anything other than declare 4 globally scoped functions and an array.  A sample fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/DkSG2/

Comment: @user2165650 Please provide some information about behaviour you're seeing in the debugger?  I assume you've tried debugging it using the browser dev tools and not just thrown it up on SO for us to fix for you?

Comment: @DazLewis hm, I'm wrong.  Thanks for correcting my bogus post.  I'll delete my misinformation now.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to troubleshoot OData calls is to copy the URI into your browser and navigate to the page.  If it does not bring you to a page with data, that means your uri is wrong.  If it does, then you are handling the resulting data incorrectly (ie if the debugger hits the success block in GetRecords, then your AddRecordsToArray or FetchRecordsCallBack is broken).

Side note - I have never seen a space before a ".[Attribute Name]".  Is that even a valid JavaScript syntax (as in your relatedProducts .push or relatedProducts .length)?